# How to expose an ingress on kuberntes to get the public IP address?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pod

I am new in `AWS` and `EKS`. Everything is going well except I am not able to figure out How to expose the ingress IP/Domain for public usage?

I tested on `minikube` and using `minikube ip`, I was able to run the application. How should I do it in `AWS EKS`?

Here is my ingress service file

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 name: platform-app-ingress
 annotations:
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
   - http:
      paths:
        - path: /?(.*)
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            serviceName: platform-app-api
            servicePort: 80
```

Any hint? what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

You have to install the ingress controller basically which handles and manages the ingress object.

there are multiple ingress controllers available in the market for the Kubernetes you can use one of as per need.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/

so your whole traffic whole will be something like

```
internet > ingress > ingress controller > Kubernetes service > pod >  container
```

you are using the annotation of **nginx**

for that controller is must need to be installed in cluster.

everything will be same just you need to install the controller using YAML or Helm chart no other configuration required.

you can read more at : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-on-digitalocean-kubernetes-using-helm

Official deployment documentation : https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/

how to install on AWS : https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#aws

**Note** :

Once you will deploy the Ingress controller it will create one Kubernetes service with the type **LoadBalancer**.

you can check this using the **Kubectl get svc -n**

Use that IP as the **public IP**. you can add this IP into the DNS and create the multiple subdomain and domain as per need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was following this link: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#aws. How can I get the `proxy-real-ip-cidr` and `AWS Certificate Manager (ACM) ID`?

Comment: you are following that tutorial but you want to terminate tls at ingress level or at LB level?

Comment: proxy-real-ip-cidr is your VPC CIDR IP & AWS Certificate Manager ID if you have any at place if not create new or if you are doing POC or testing just follow above method only.https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#network-load-balancer-nlb

Comment: you can terminate the TLS and SSL at the ingress controller level also consider the ingress controller as the Nginx service and Ingres object or YAML file as routing configuration. once service or NLB is deployed and pod running node need to touch anything just change the ingress object or path config using yaml you have one above.

Comment: No, I do not want to terminate tls and I am doing for actual production. BTW I have. updated. real-ip-cidr and certificate manager ID. How to verify and collect the public IP address?

Comment: I tried ` Kubectl get svc -n` but getting only https://ibb.co/J7GhVJL

Comment: check which namspaces you have. `kubectl get svc -n ingress-nginx` if you have installed your controller in that namespace using default yaml

Comment: you got the external Ip you can use it in DNS as CNAME and creat the subdomain  and use that subdomain in ingres file

Comment: here very simple exampe : https://matthewpalmer.net/kubernetes-app-developer/articles/kubernetes-ingress-guide-nginx-example.html

Comment: if you want to route by host name : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#hostname-wildcards

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the ingress endpoint at least in between, please refer https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/.
The correct communication is:
`internet -> ingress endpoint/LB -> ingress controller -> ingress object -> routing rule -> service -> available pod`
In this case you don't have to worry about public IP.
However, if you use service directly with type=loadbalancer you will get External IP field while describing service.